# Same Code is producing different outputs for Java 7 & 8

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, comparator

On Giving Input as **91912323** it gives output as **33221199** for Java 8 while in Java 7 the output is **11223399**.

The problem statement is also provided for your reference.

Any help would be appreciated.

> A string consists of digits from 1-9 will be passed as input. The
>   program must print the digits sorted based on the number of
>   occurrence. If one or more digits occur the same number of times, the
>   smallest digit must be printed first.
>
> Input Format: The first line will contain the N digits from 1-9
>
> Boundary Conditions: 3 <= N <= 30
>
> Output Format: The digits sorted based on the number of occurrence.
>
> Example Input/Output 1:
>
> Input: 4443338993
>
> Output: 3333444998
>
> Explanation: 3 occurs the most number of times (four times). Hence it
>   is printed first. 4 occurs thrice and hence printed after the 3s. 9
>   occurs twice and hence printed after the 4s. 8 occurs only once and
>   hence printed after 9.
>
> Example Input/Output 2:
>
> Input: 95559998228
>
> Output: 99995552288
>
> Explanation: Here 2 and 8 occurs twice. Hence 2 being the smaller
>   digit is printed before 8.

```
package E001;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

/**
 *
 * @author Anagh
 */

public class CharOccurrences {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String input = br.readLine();
        char[] arr = input.toCharArray();
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if(!map.containsKey(String.valueOf(arr[i])))
            {
                map.put(String.valueOf(arr[i]), 1);
            }
            else
            {
                map.put(String.valueOf(arr[i]), map.get(String.valueOf(arr[i]))+1);
            }
        }
        TreeMap<String, Integer> output = sortByValue(map);
        printMap(output);

    }
    public static TreeMap<String, Integer> sortByValue (HashMap<String, Integer> map) 
    {
    ValueComparator vc =  new ValueComparator(map);
    TreeMap<String,Integer> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(vc);
    sortedMap.putAll(map);
    return sortedMap;
    }

    private static void printMap(TreeMap<String, Integer> map) {
        String key;
        int value;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) 
        {
            key = entry.getKey();
            value = entry.getValue();
            for(int j = 0; j < value; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(key);
            }
    }        
    }

}
class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    Map<String, Integer> map;

    public ValueComparator(Map<String, Integer> base) {
        this.map = base;
    } 
    @Override
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        if (map.get(a) > map.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        } // returning 0 would merge keys 
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems interesting question, but you could find this out for yourself with logs in functions, you posted lots of code here, dont expect anyone to debug it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Output: 99995552288
>
> Explanation: Here 2 and 8 occurs twice. **Hence 2 being the smaller digit is printed before 8**.

Your comparator doesn't implement that logic. In order for it to implement that logic, it should be :

```
public int compare(String a, String b) {
    if (map.get(a) > map.get(b)) {
        return -1;
    } else if (map.get(a) < map.get(b)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your comparator is breaking its contract, you should add a case how it should be sorted when there is exact number of occurances, for example smaller number first.

Comment: Was this meant to be a comment?